# Database doesn't save values using overloading methods

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I can't understand why is the database either not saving the values I enter or is it the method which I am using to pull all the data not working correctly. It doesn't throw any errors it just doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
    private static final String QUERY_TRIANGLE_CREATE_TABLE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TRIANGLE_TABLE_NAME + " (" + TRIANGLE_COL_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                TRIANGLE_VALUE_A + " TEXT, " + TRIANGLE_VALUE_C + "TEXT, " + TRIANGLE_VALUE_B + " TEXT, " + TRIANGLE_RESULT + " TEXT," + TRIANGLE_HISTORY_INFORMATION + " TEXT" +  "  );";


public void insertTriangleCalc(String a,String b, String c,String d,String e){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TRIANGLE_VALUE_A,a);
    values.put(TRIANGLE_VALUE_B,b);
    values.put(TRIANGLE_VALUE_C,c);
    values.put(TRIANGLE_RESULT,d);
    values.put(TRIANGLE_HISTORY_INFORMATION,e);

    database.insert("triangle", null, values);
    database.close();

}
public void insertTriangleCalc(String a,String b, String c,String d){
    SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(TRIANGLE_VALUE_A,a);
    values.put(TRIANGLE_VALUE_B,b);
    values.put(TRIANGLE_RESULT,c);
    values.put(TRIANGLE_HISTORY_INFORMATION,d);

    database.insert("triangle", null, values);
    database.close();}
public List<Triangle> ObjectRead() {

    List<Triangle> valuesList = new ArrayList<>();

    String sql = "SELECT  * FROM triangle ORDER BY id DESC";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(sql, null);

    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {

            int id = Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("id")));
            String valueA = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("valueA"));
            String valueB = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("valueB"));
            String valueC="0";
            try {

            } catch (Exception e){

            }

            String result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("result"));
            String history = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("history"));

            Triangle triangle = new Triangle();
            triangle.id = id;
            triangle.valueA = valueA;
            triangle.valueB  = valueB;
            triangle.valueC = valueC;
            triangle.Result = result;
            triangle.history = history;
            valuesList.add(triangle);

        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();

    return valuesList;
}
```

Can anyone have a look at it and help me figure out what am I not setting up properly. It works for public void insertTriangleCalc(String a,String b, String c,String d) , but not for public void insertTriangleCalc(String a,String b, String c,String d,String e).

Comment: I used this because I am not always putting values in "value c" and I want to return 0 or am I doing it wrong ?

Comment: Can you paste all the constant you used in the query above

Comment: If the column will take a null value then just pass in a null value instead of `c` rather than having two methods

Comment: please edit the question and ask it properly, You have mentioned same method name and arguments for working and not working scenario.

Comment: My bad, it is public void insertTriangleCalc(String a,String b, String c,String d,String e) that is not working properly will edit it

Comment: @Psypher  

private static final String TRIANGLE_TABLE_NAME = "triangle";
    private static final String TRIANGLE_COL_ID = "id";
    private static final String TRIANGLE_VALUE_A = "valueA";
    private static final String TRIANGLE_VALUE_B = "valueB";
    private static final String TRIANGLE_VALUE_C = "valueC";
    private static final String TRIANGLE_RESULT = "result";
    private static final String TRIANGLE_HISTORY_INFORMATION = "history";

Comment: I have somewhat found where the problem is. In the ObjectRead method, it queries the DB and finds the values however it doesn't go into the if statement. I can't find the reason why though.

Answer (score 0):

Decided to check from top to bottom and the whole thing was happening because of a missing empty space TRIANGLE_VALUE_C + "TEXT, "
                                        <- here. This has now been resolved and it can finally store data correctly.